# How to properly apply backgroundcolor on a text in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

```
internal string Select(RichTextBox rtb, int index, int length)
    {
        TextRange textRange = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);

        if (textRange.Text.Length >= (index + length))
        {
            TextPointer start = textRange.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(index, LogicalDirection.Forward);
            TextPointer end = textRange.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(index + length, LogicalDirection.Backward);
            rtb.Selection.Select(start, end); 
            rtb.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue)); 
        }
        return rtb.Selection.Text;
    }
```

whenever ApplyPropertyValue is called to change the backgroundcolor of selected text, it works great for the first time but it does not properly adjust the background color of the selected text segment on the second time it is called. I suspect this has to do with offsets of the document somehow being messed up after the function has been called.

What is a good way to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this (it needs a logic a bit more complex then yours), otherwise yes: you have problems with offsets!

```
private static TextPointer GetTextPointAt(TextPointer from, int pos)
{
        TextPointer ret = from;
        int i = 0;

        while ((i < pos) && (ret != null))
        {
            if ((ret.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Backward) == TextPointerContext.Text) || (ret.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Backward) == TextPointerContext.None))
                i++;

            if (ret.GetPositionAtOffset(1, LogicalDirection.Forward) == null)
                return ret;

            ret = ret.GetPositionAtOffset(1, LogicalDirection.Forward);
        }

        return ret;
}

internal string Select(RichTextBox rtb, int offset, int length, Color color)
{
        // Get text selection:
        TextSelection textRange = rtb.Selection;

        // Get text starting point:
        TextPointer start = rtb.Document.ContentStart;

        // Get begin and end requested:
        TextPointer startPos = GetTextPointAt(start, offset);
        TextPointer endPos = GetTextPointAt(start, offset + length);

        // New selection of text:
        textRange.Select(startPos, endPos);

        // Apply property to the selection:
        textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(color));

        // Return selection text:
        return rtb.Selection.Text;
}
```

And then use it in this way (I'm selecting from first character to the fifth in RED)  :

```
this.Select(this.myRichTextBox, 0, 5, Colors.Red);
```

Comment: Spectacular answer. Thank you.

Comment: @MAXE, my level of gratitude to you is at maxemum.

Comment: @LiviuSosu glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

First of all, great answer by MAXE because it clearly demonstrated to me the underlying problem I was having: that one needs to remember that the flow document controls in WPF are dealing with markup, not raw text.  Hence the underlying problem is to skip over the markup until you are actually dealing with the text inside the containing element.

The problem with this solution is that it is horrendously slow.  As an example, an application that is selecting around ~150 pieces of text takes ~20 seconds to execute using this method and all but ~20ms of that was spent selecting text!

There is no general solution to this problem that will work in all scenarios but it pays to think carefully about what you are trying to achieve and optimise accordingly.  A common scenario is to create a single run (paragraph, etc) and put a block of text in there, then select/highlight text within that single element.  In this scenario you know there is only one 'element' so you can do the following which will achieve the same result as above:

```
   internal static TextPointer GetOffsetTextPointer(this TextPointer start, int offset)
    {
        return start.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward).GetPositionAtOffset(offset);
    }
```

For reference, the **GetInsertionPosition** method will skip over the starting element markup, to the point where your text actually begins, then the **GetPositionAtOffset** method gets the actual pointer in one single call.  For comparison, the above example now takes less than 2 seconds to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you MAXE for this great solution.

You might run into trouble having linebreaks and other invisible characters in your rtf text. To fix this, add an offset corrector at the beginning of the method:

```
// Get the text between start and offset
string rtfBoxContentToOffset = rtfBoxContent.Substring(0, offset);

// check for linebreaks or other and decrement the offset
foreach (char character in rtfBoxContentToOffset)           
   if (character == '\r' || character == '\n') offset--;
```